# When is ${n \choose k} > (n-k)(k+1) + (n-k-1)k$?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-mathematics

I have two algorithms that output the same result for an input value of a non-negative integer k and a list of n elements, where $1 \leq k \leq n$.

However, the two algorithms are very different in terms of efficiency.  One algorithm (call it $X$) uses a binomial approach and requires ${n \choose k}$ time to complete; the other algorithm (call it $Y$) is quadratic and requires $(n-k)(k+1) + (n-k-1)k$ time to complete.

Obviously, when $n$ is large and $k$ is not near the ends, I want to use algorithm $Y$; however, when $k$ is close to 1 or close to $n$, or when $n$ is small, I want to use algorithm $X$.

Right now, I just calculate both numbers, and look at which one is smaller.  But this feels like a lot of unnecessary computation.  Can you figure out a simpler way to determine when (n Choose k) is smaller?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial[n%2C+k]+%3E+%28n+-+k%29+%28k+%2B+1%29+%2B+%28n+-+k+-+1%29+k%26%26n%3Ek%3E0) too.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just figured it out practically from a spreadsheet.  I should use Algorithm X when:

- k = 1
- k = n
- k = n-1
- k = 2 and n <= 8
- k = 3 and n <= 5